# Formatting a DateTime to a shorthand month in English

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I have a bit of code that's formatting the shorthand month name, see below, but I need the value to always return in English. This code currently seems to be translated into the appropriate language somehow?

Any ideas?  Many thanks!

```
Response.write(myDateTimeValue.ToString("MMM"));  // Needs to always return Jan for all languages
```

Answer (score 13):

```
month.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

InvariantCulture is explicitly for situations where you always need the result to be the same, and always matches en-US. There is no need to create a new instance of CultureInfo.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by passing a culture info object to the `ToString()` method as follows:

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
 Response.write(month.ToString("MMM", ci));
```

Answer (score 2):

> month.ToString("MMM",
>   CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

Answer (score 2):

```
month.ToString("MMM", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ToString` passing in a `IFormatProvider` that is for the English culture:

```
Response.write(month.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
```